# Curved Bottom Navigation Bar for React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I saw a package for bottom navigation for Flutter which looks very nice.

[Curved Navigation Bar (Flutter)](https://github.com/rafalbednarczuk/curved_navigation_bar)

Basically, it will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mid1U.gif)

I am trying to replicate it in React Native (UI first, then will work on Animation) but not successful. Is it actually possible to replicate this in React Native?

The closest I can get is as shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLwAN.png) image. However I used 4 different shapes positioned as absolute to achieve this.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoOyl.png) image differentiates the shapes I used (Gray, Orange, Red and Blue) to form the navigation bar.

Please advice me if there is a way to make this perfect (better without the workarounds like I did).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The close approach is to use Views like this.

[image]

Mask off the red part on yellow or do apply same background color to red. It will look like this.

[image]

Since I couldn't found how to mask it, I just applied background color to the red color View.

Then you can use animations and interpolation to move the entire shape on the click event.

And the final product will look like this.

[image]

I've published the same on https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-curved-navigation-bar

Or you can check out and clone the project on [github](https://github.com/prashant9912/ReactNative_Curved_Navigation_Bar)

Comment: Thank you very much for this package. Currently I am using simple navigation styles since I could not achieve it. Now, this package will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is library [react-native-tabbar-interaction](https://github.com/Mindinventory/react-native-tabbar-interaction) , you can have a try with it. Look similar as you need

Comment: This is really nice the only problem is we cant add more than 3 tab and also is not responsive when layout changes